# System or advices to allow players to handle their downtime

Tags: dnd-5e, downtime

I'm currently dming for a group of 4 level 2 that took control of a small goblin village. They have a week of downtime ahead of them (they are waiting for a delivery to resolve their current quest) and they want to improve the village (maybe start building their own stronghold or attract more free workforce to power their futur plans).

I could ask them what they want to do, day by day or globally, and rule the outcome, but I would like to offer them some control over their downtime and reduce the dming load of that aspect.

Are there some downtime system that work fine with dnd5 to handle small scale settlements management that I could give to my player, so my role would just be to validate the results and maybe throw some events time to time ?

Edit :
Ultimatly, I would like to confer more power over the world to my players, but within some boundary (not because I don't trust them, but you don't really make real choices when you are without limits). 
What I seek is a tool to change the world in the game that I can give to my players, which offer them some options and let them extrapolate the results. The basic system proposed by the DMG is a little to abstract and general for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Do you really need a subsystem? Asking and having a conversation is a lot simpler and gets to the heart of the matter, and you can use skill checks to determine outcomes.

Comment: Have you read the downtime rules provided in the DMG, and is there a reason they are not sufficient for this?  Basically, what have you tried or considered so far?  We don't know exactly what your problem is and the question currently reads as an idea generation/recommendation question, which doesn't really work for this site.

Comment: @okeefe maybe I'm overthinking this, but some task can't be resolved with skill checks, and even with skill check I would be up to me to say how much they succed considering their skill check results 
Ultimatly, I would like to confer more power over the world to my players, but within some boundary (not because I don't trust them, but you don't really make real choices when you are without limits).